# Python: Wait until function finishes inside the function

Tags: python, selenium

I am using selenium to scrape some data.

This is my code, simplified:

```
def get_usrs():

 #DO SOMETHING
 
 def scroll_down():
   #SCROLL UNTIL ARRIVES TO THE BOTTOM OF THE PAGE

 #CONTINUE WITH GET_USRS()
```

The problem is that when the code gets to `scroll_down()` it doesn't wait until it finishes but continues with `get_usrs()` and obviously encounters an error.

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: is the method `scroll_down` defined inside the `get_users`? if yes, have you called it explicitly?

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia yes, it's defined inside. Now I tried to call it but I get the same error

Comment: Solved, the code was executed with 'try except' now it's not. Works fine!

Answer (score 0):

So, my code was running with:

```
try:
    get_usrs()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Now it's running with:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_usrs()
```

Works fine.